# Temporarily merged a branch into our development branch, want to undo

Tags: git

so i seem to have created some git headaches for myself, wondering if someone's experience could help. I'll try explain clearly:

- I have a **development** branch, which auto-builds onto our staging server
- I have another branch **feature/a** - it has work in it that extends beyond **development**
- I wanted to get **feature/a** temporarily onto our staging server, so did it the only way that is currently possible - i merged it into **development**
- I then reset HEAD on my local machine for **development**, to a previous commit I had made of **development**, and it has been working well locally
- now when I try to push my local **development**, I get a message that my local branch is behind, so I should pull before pushing
- however, I actually want my local **development** to become the remote **development** again, and for feature/a to continue separately for now as it has been

I'm not super-clear as to what git command sequence would give me the above resolution, and I really don't want to lose my (or anyone else's!) commit history!

Comment: This looks like a mess.  Why is merging the feature branch into `development` the _only_ way to deploy it?  I mean, can't you deploy any branch you want?

Comment: Yes, that makes total sense - but it's because I work in a company where that's in the control of other people, and as insensible as it is, there's nothing I can do about it right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for feature/a to continue separately for now as it has been

If feature/a is currently represented by the development branch (in its present state)

```
git checkout -b feature-a development
# or, with Git 2.23
git switch -c feature-a development
```

That will create a new local branch for `feature-a`, and you are free to reset development.

> I actually want my local development to become the remote development again, and

```
 git fetch
 # make sure you don't have any work in progress first
 git checkout development
 git reset --hard origin/development
```